# Как сделать так, чтоб 3 числа складывались столько раз, сколько нужно, по порядку?

Tags: python-3.x

f1+f2+f3+f1+f2+f3 и так столько раз, сколько мне нужно, ввел 10 будет: f1+f2+f3+f1+f2+f3+f1+f2+f3+f1

Comment: уточните задачу - откуда эти числа берутся?, что мешает сделать `(f1 + f2 + f3) * n` :) в школе же во 2 классе умножение проходят

Comment: нам известно, что f1=1 f2=2 f3=3. Нужно сделать так, что б было ровно столько чисел, сколько введется

Comment: Если введется число 10 то будет 1+2+3+1+2+3+1+2+3+1

Answer (score 3):

понял, что имел автор кажется

т.е. если вводят 5, то будет `f1 + f2 + f3 + f1 + f2`, а если введут 1, то будет просто `f1`

```
fs = [1, 2, 3]

n = 10

res = 0

for i in range(n):
    res += fs[i % len(fs)]

print(res)
```

код можно свернуть в 1 строчку

```
fs = [1, 2, 3]

n = 10

res = sum(fs[i % len(fs)] for i in range(n))

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
n = 10
print(sum((lst * (n // len(lst) + 1))[:n]))
```

Вывод:

```
19
```

В чём суть:

- "размножаем" список с запасом, так, чтобы там было заведомо немного больше элементов, чем нам нужно
- берём с помощью среза из получившегося списка сколько нужно элементов
- суммируем и печатаем

Answer (score 0):

```
var=input('введите выражение')
#2+2*2+2
print(eval(var))
#8
```

upd eval не безопасная функция её исспользование на непроверенных данных не допустимо

Comment: нет, вводится не выражение, а количество раз, сколько должно быть чисел, надеюсь понятно

Comment: ты имеешь ввиду умножение? типа числа 4 нужно 5 раз, значит 5*4

Comment: нет, не 4 числа нужно по 5 раз, а нужно всего 5 чисел, т.е. 4 по одному разу, а одно два раза

Answer (score 0):

```
f1 = 1 # Первое число
f2 = 2 # Второе число
f3 = 3 # Третье число
sm = 0 # Сумма
n = int( input( 'Количество раз ' ) ) # Вводим повторы
i = 0 # Обнуляем счётчик
while i < n :  # Повторяем до тех пор, пока не закончатся повторы
    i += 1 # Увеличиваем счётчик
    if i % 3 == 1 :
        sm += f1 # При первом повторе добавляем число 1
    if i % 3 == 2 :
        sm += f2 # При втором повторе добавляем число 2
    if i % 3 == 0 :
        sm += f3 # Далее добавляем число 3 и так далее
print( sm ) # Выводим результат
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Добавил комментарии

Answer (score 0):

[itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) строит бесконечный цикл. [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) отрезает нужной длины кусок:

```
@>>> print(*itertools.islice(itertools.cycle((1, 10, 100)), 10))
1 10 100 1 10 100 1 10 100 1

@>>> sum(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle((1, 10, 100)), 10))
334
```